# I get the following error on Report Builder and Visual Studio after sucessful installation of ODTwithODAC183

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2019, reportbuilder, odac

My Visual Studio and Report Builder are not working. I have Visual Studio 2019 Professional, and I have tried installing following ODCs butin Visual Studio I keep getting the error message "Unable to connect to data source.The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded.  Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for local reports and on the report server for published reports." and Report Builder error message "The selected data extension ORACLE is not installed or cannot be loaded. Verify that the selected data extension is installed on the client for local reports and on the report server for published reports."

1. win32_11gR2_client
2. ODTwithODAC183 (this ODT wont allow me to install as it gives Visual Studio not installed error even though it is installed on my computer).
3. ODAC122011_x64
4. V1020746-01
5. Oracle-Client-for-Microsoft-Tools
6. Visual Studios 2019 Pro

Installed multiple ODCs but problem still persists.